# Converting Tensorflow 2 saved model into a Tensorflow-Lite model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to convert a Tensorflow 2 saved model into a Tensorflow-Lite model using this script:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(DIR)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

but I get this error:

```
tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: <unknown>:0: error: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): requires all operands and results to have compatible element types
types
<unknown>:0: note: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): see current operation: %1 = "tf.Identity"(%arg0) {device = ""} : (tensor<1x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>) -> tensor<1x?x?x3xui8>
```

Using:

Tensorflow 2.3.1

Python 3.8.5

Windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42065

Comment: @Frank Yep, I didn't have tf-nightly installed. I do get this error, "TFLite interpreter needs to link Flex delegate in order to run the model since it contains the following flex op(s): Flex ops: FlexConcatV2, FlexStridedSlice", but it still spits out a tflite model so I'll test it out and see if it works.